# How to change color of all columns in cxGrid if column name contains specific text

Tags: delphi, devexpress

I am using SQL to create calendar table horizontally in cxGrid2DBTableView depending on Date from and Date to, that user choose.
Because of that column names are always different, example in picture bellow:

[image]

I would like to change the color of values for non working days, which means I have to mark all columns that containts %Sub% or %Ned% and change their colors.

This is example of code that I use when I know the column name:

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1VremeCustomDrawCell(Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ACanvas: TcxCanvas; AViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
begin
ACanvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
ACanvas.Brush.Color := clMoneyGreen;   
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the GridView's `OnCustomDrawCell` event handler with `AViewInfo.Item.Name`.

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1CustomDrawCell(
  Sender: TcxCustomGridTableView; ACanvas: TcxCanvas;
  AViewInfo: TcxGridTableDataCellViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
begin
  if(Pos('Sub', AViewInfo.Item.Name) <> 0) or (Pos('Ned', AViewInfo.Item.Name) <> 0) then
  begin
    ACanvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
    ACanvas.Brush.Color := clMoneyGreen;
  end;
end;
```

If you prefer to work with captions, you can use `AViewInfo.Item.Caption` instead of `AViewInfo.Item.Name`. Anyhow, I suggest you to never work with captions because they could change in multilanguage applications.

And if you want to draw the column's header, you can use the GridView's `OnCustomDrawColumnHeader` event handler:

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1CustomDrawColumnHeader(
  Sender: TcxGridTableView; ACanvas: TcxCanvas;
  AViewInfo: TcxGridColumnHeaderViewInfo; var ADone: Boolean);
begin
  if(Pos('Sub', AViewInfo.Column.Name) <> 0) or (Pos('Ned', AViewInfo.Column.Name) <> 0) then
  begin
    ACanvas.Font.Color := clBlack;
    ACanvas.Brush.Color := clMoneyGreen;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: The first one did exaclty what I wanted, but the secont example of code did nothing. It should change colour of header? Could you maybe help me with first example, now cells have no borders or frame, is there an easy way to paint it to black?

Comment: @FilipJankovic: Yes, it should change the header's color (but note that it will not work if you're using DevExpress skins. In that case, it will be much more difficult because you will need to paint the column's header from scratch and setting the `ADone` parameter to `True`). Anyhow, I've created an example project and I have no problems with borders (see [this picture](https://i.ibb.co/dJg2N0k/dx-colors.png))